# An illegal reflective access operation has occurred., While migrate the Spring boot application from java 11 to 17

Tags: jdbi, jdbi3, jdbi3-core

An illegal reflective access operation has occurred., While migrate the Spring boot application from java 11 to 17.

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.skife.jdbi.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:./lib/jdbi.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.skife.jdbi.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Changed the java version from 11 to 17.